# COM Interop with .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, com, .net-6.0

We have a .NET class library written in C# that we're trying to upgrade to .NET 6 from .NET Framework v2.0. With .NET 2.0, the library is instantiated/consumed via C++ code which imports the library's .TLB.

In order to consume .NET 6 libraries using COM, you now have to add attributes to your C# interfaces/classes yourself, as well as the .csproj, so that an extra DLL called .comhost.dll is created at compile time, which you then register using regsvr32 as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com. Using type libraries is no longer supported out of the box but I tried generating a TLB using the "dscom" utility here https://github.com/dspace-group/dscom. Unfortunately it kept failing with an error saying System.Windows.Forms could not be found and having spent a couple of days trying to get it work, I've given up.

Microsoft's tutorial doesn't suggest the best way of instantiating the newly created COM object, so I'm wondering if it's a case of going back to the old methods of calling CoCreateInstance or LoadLibrary, or if there's a better way? It would've been nice if the TLB-based approach still worked.

Comment: The TLB-based approach still works, but there's not .NET core/5/6 tool to create it (and yes, this is dumb, Microsoft should do it). With a .NET Framework compatible C# code, you can use the "old" .NET framework tools regasm or tlbexp to create a tlb. You can also learn how tlb are created from scratch (using MIDL compiler). It's pretty easy as you can decompile any .TLB using a tool such as OLEView from Windows SDK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer and get inspiration from it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to clarify, are you saying that regasm or tlbexp will work on .NET5+ assemblies?

Comment: No, I'm saying you can share C# COM code between your .NET core/5/6 project and a "shadow" .NET Framework project and use .NET Framework tool on the produced .NET Framework dll

Comment: Ok I think I know what you mean - like creating a .NET Framework wrapper around my .NET 6 code?

Comment: You create say a mycom.cs file and use it simultaneously in two projects: one for .NET Framework and one .NET core/5/6. Then you can build a .tlb from the .NET framework project that you can use from .NET core/5/6

Comment: Could be related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49695476/using-com-object-in-net-core-2-0/49701795#49701795

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an update on this. I managed to generate a type library using the dscom utility. I had to provide an additional argument called "--asmpath" to point to the location of the .NET runtime assemblies (in this case C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\6.0.0) that my assembly depended on, and then it worked.

Comment: That is not a great idea, this exposes the users to very hard to diagnose failure when the machine gets a .NET update.  At issue is that the dependency on Winforms was previously taken care of by a stable file, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.tlb, but Microsoft no longer provides these for .NETCore.  The equivalent is now generated by dscom, but its content is not stable.  Particularly the [Guid] of an interface or class can easily change.  You really do want to get rid of the dependency, it is almost always easy to do by substituting your own type.

Comment: The dependency in question is System.Windows.Forms, which we use to instantiate forms from other third-party assemblies for localisation purposes, so I'm not sure how we would subsititure it. The dscom approach is not ideal for sure, but the alternative suggested by Microsoft was writing an IDL file by hand or embedding the existing type library in the new version of our library. We don't expect the interfaces and types in the library to change, so the type library only needs to be generated if it does. We will also be installing a particular version of the .NET runtime alongside our app

Comment: For me it says 5 times "Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621)". --asmpath does not help.